# Exporting data from a datagirdview to an excel sheet with decimals retained

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am working on an `C# windows forms application` which export data from a `DataGridView` to excel using `Interop Open Library 15.0`. My data in DataGridView is such that it contains few column which has float type data rounded upto three decimal points.

For example, I have a number 10.000 in my DataGridView but when I export it to excel it just export 10 instead of 10.000.

I am using the following code to export data

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();


            // creating new WorkBook within Excel application
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);


            // creating new Excelsheet in workbook
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet indexWorkSheet = null;
            indexWorkSheet = workbook.Sheets[1];
            // changing the name of active sheet
            indexWorkSheet.Name = "Index Summary";

            indexWorkSheet.get_Range("A1").Style.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
            indexWorkSheet.get_Range("A10", "A30").Style.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
            string filelocation;
            SaveFileDialog SaveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
            if (SaveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filelocation = SaveFile.FileName;



                for (int i = 1; i < dataGridViewIndex.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    indexWorkSheet.Cells[9, i + 3] = dataGridViewIndex.Columns[i - 1].HeaderCell.Value;
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < dataGridViewIndex.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    indexWorkSheet.Cells[i + 9, 3] = dataGridViewIndex.Rows[i - 1].HeaderCell.Value;

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewIndex.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridViewIndex.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {

                        indexWorkSheet.Cells[i + 10, j + 4] = dataGridViewIndex.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
 workbook.SaveAs(filelocation, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
```

My DataGridView is an in the screenshot below
[image]

I wanted to export above data with BBL/Day and Avg Price with three decimal points no matter what the value is.

**Is there a good way to solve this?**

Comment: Have you tried Open XML SDK ? If you want I can provide an answer with Open XML SDK to achieve this

Comment: I tried XML but I had issues exporting data with the same format. it just takes everything as text doesn't consider what type it is. So, I just used interop

Comment: You misunderstood .. anyway generating Exel spreadsheet is possible by using Open XML SDK - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx  .. Just have a read :) ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`10.000` IS `10`.  Excel is using "general" formatting by default which doesn't show any trailing zeros. If you want to format the number on the excel side you'll have to explicitly do that.

```
indexWorkSheet.Cells[i + 10, j + 4] = dataGridViewIndex.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
indexWorkSheet.Cells[i + 10, j + 4].NumberFormat = "#,##0.000";  
// or whatever format is appropriate.
```

However I would make one other change:

- Work with *ranges* instead of *cells*.  Every cell access is a COM call which adds *significant* overhead to the process.  If you ran a decent profiles against it I would be willing to bet that the vast majority of your time is spent on the cell access.

Put your data into an array and set the value in one call (and set the format for the range as well):

```
int[,] data = new int[rows,cols];

... loop
    data[i,j] = value;

var range = indexworksheet.get_Range(...);
range.Value = data;
range.NumberFormat = "#,##0.000";
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted this number format only for two columns as mentioned

Comment: So add that condition to the example.  The point is to set the number formatting on the Excel side, not the C# side.

Answer (score 0):

```
               for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewIndex.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridViewIndex.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            int digitcount = 4;
                            indexWorkSheet.Cells[i + 10, j + 4] = dataGridViewIndex.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString("F"+digitcount);
                        }
                    }
```

Try this to format the string.

Comment: That would work, but I believe it would cause the excel cell to be formatted as "text" which may not be the right approach.

Comment: As on d-stanley says, maintain one list<column name>(Collections) for change the number format..